# Sort file name with delimiter in batch file

Tags: windows, sorting, batch-file, cmd

I need to sort the list of file names by their version number with least first, in windows batch script.
The file names are like:

```
2_0_0to2_0_1
2_0_1_to2_0_2
...
2_0_12_to2_0_13
...
```

I've tried dir and sort in Windows but it seems to only look at char positions which wouldn't work in the case of double digits. In Linux, I've done this with: ls *.txt | sort -n -t _ -k1 -k2 -k3. How to do this on Windows. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK: Windows does not have any native natural sort utilities.  You will have to download a 3rd party tool. Try Sort in this http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But that tool doesn't support sort capability.

Comment: Can you sort by date/time to get what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR %%x IN (*) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1-6delims=_to" %%a IN ("%%~x") DO (
        SET "g1=0%%a"
        SET "g2=0%%b"
        SET "g3=0%%c"
        SET "g4=0%%d"
        SET "g5=0%%e"
        SET "g6=0%%f"
        SET "$!g1:~-2!!g2:~-2!!g3:~-2!!g4:~-2!!g5:~-2!!g6:~-2!=%%~x"
    )
)
FOR /f "tokens=2delims==" %%a IN ('set "$"') DO ECHO %%~a
```

Comment: Clever solution Endoro, the sort may not need the /r.  I get 12 before 1 before 0.  It works well otherwise.  The OP may need further padding but that's easy.

Comment: @foxidrive thank you very much for your comment. My English ist not at it's best, so I'm not sure what `with least first` means?

Comment: least first means less first, or lowest numbers first.  So 2.0.0 and then 2.0.1 followed by 2.0.12

Comment: Thanks to you both for the perfect answer. But I have one more question. I understand your script until the last for. What is 'set "$"'?  I don't see how the variables are put in order after it is stored in the 2 for loops prior.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Thank you Endoro. But I don't see where the file names are put in order. Could you help please? I am new to this. It seems to me that you set $xyz=abc, then assuming the $xyz is sorted, retrieve abc from the sorted $xyz map.

Comment: The file names are sorted in an associative array `$`, to be sorted is a property of such arrays in cmd.

Comment: Excellent idea and approach! Thank you Endoro.