# How to rename Windows files using extracted substring from current names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I have a directory of academic papers that were named using the convention below:

```
Author1-(Year)-Title.pdf
```

For example,

```
Jones-(2011)-XXX.pdf
Smith-(2002)-YYY.pdf
Johnson-(2015)-ZZZ.pdf
```

I would like to rename them as

```
(2011)-Jones-XXX.pdf
(2002)-Smith-YYY.pdf
(2015)-Johnson-ZZZ.pdf
```

That is, to extract the year from the file name and put it in front.

I tried the following code, which did not work

```
    Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    Set "Year=2013"
    Set "Replace="""

    For %%a in (*.pdf) Do (
        Set "NewName=(%year%)-%%~a"
        Ren "%%a" "%NewName%-File:%Year%=%Replace%!" 
    )

    Pause&Exit
```

Comment: is use of the batch requirement? if no prefer some scripting language (my favorite is Python). read file name split by '-' into fields and then reorder fields.

Comment: additionally i would suggest removing () from names - not nice practice to use those in file names

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  The use of a batch file is not a requirement, but my Python skill is awful, much worst than DOS command language.

Comment: I will give it a shot, however, as it appears to require only to import os and using pre-built methods to tokenize the fields and re-order them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b "*.pdf"') do (
    echo ren "%%a-%%b-%%c" "%%b-%%a-%%c"
)
```

this will only `echo` the intended rename command.If it looks ok remove the `echo` word.

Comment: Thank you, this works when I put a space between delims=-" and %%a in the above.   When there are hyphenated author names, it simply swaps the names, but I worked around that by replace "Smith-Jones" with "Smith&Jones"

Comment: @mhla - thanks - fixed. If there  names containing `-` you can try to split the names by brackets...

Answer (score 1):

In case XXX also contains hyphens I'd suggest using `tokens=1,2*` to stop parsing the remainder of the file name.
I'd also remove the parentheses, when the year is first place there is no need to further emphasize it.

```
@Echo off
for /f "tokens=1-2* delims=-()" %%A in (
  'Dir  /b "*-(*)-*.pdf"'
) do Ren "%%A-(%%B)-%%C" "%%B-%%A-%%C"
```

Sample output

```
> dir /b
2002-Smith-YYY.pdf
2011-Jones-XXX.pdf
2015-Johnson-ZZZ.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you, i have an error running this ("The syntax of the command is incorrect.") and I am trying to figure out why that is occurring.

Comment: @mhla I tested it succesfully here. Did you copy and paste the source?

Comment: I finally figured it out.  Thank you !!.  It was the copying and pasting into a non-ISO text editor

Answer (score 0):

Derived form [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17882466/sort-file-name-with-delimiter-in-batch-file) - it works:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

FOR %%x IN (*.pdf) DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a IN ("%%~x") DO (
        SET "Author=%%a"
        SET "Year=%%b"
        SET "Title=%%c"

        ren %%x !Year!-!Author!-!Title!
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you, I received an error running this ("in not expected here") , and I'm still trying to find out what caused the error

Comment: I tried again and it worked fine. Maybe something got lost while copying the sample? The help for "for" tells "/F" - on my system it seems to make no difference if I use "/f" or "/F", but maybe yours?

Comment: I tried it again and it works now.  It was my cutting and pasting into a non-standard text editor that messed up the <CR> and for loop.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a reliable way of doing what you are asking for even if the author part contains `-` on its own. The title portion may even contain `(` and `)`, but the author part must not. So this is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILES=.\*-(????)-*.pdf" & rem // (basic pattern to match correct files)
set "_REGEX=^[^()][^()]*-([0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789])-.*\.pdf$" ^
    & rem // (precise filter to exclude files violating the demanded pattern)

if not defined _REGEX set "_REGEX=.*" & rem // (avoid trouble with empty filter)
rem // Loop through all matching files:
for /F "eol=: tokens=1,2,* delims=()" %%F in ('
    dir /B /A:-D "%_FILES%" ^| findstr /I /R /C:"%_REGEX%"
') do (
    rem // Store the extracted file name parts:
    set "LEFT=%%F" & set "YEAR=%%G" & set "REST=%%H"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Reassemble the name and rename the file:
    ECHO ren "!LEFT!(!YEAR!)!REST!" "(!YEAR!)-!LEFT!!REST:*-=!"
    endlocal
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

**After having verified the correct output, remove the upper-case `ECHO` command to actually rename files.**